# Embeded Tomcat version 9 Not Working to create container for API

Tags: java, spring, gradle, tomcat9

I am trying to run tomcat container using dependency **'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.65'**.
While using this the I am not able to start container, If I move to version **8.5.41** or any version of **tomcat-embeded-core 8.***, it is working fine. I am using CFXServlet for servlet. Below is code example.

Package imported:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDef;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterMap;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
```

Code snippet I used :

```
Tomcat tServer = new Tomcat();
tServer.setHostname('127.0.0.1');
tServer.setPort(4434);
tServer.getHost().setAppBase(".");
Context ctx = tServer.addContext("/", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
            
tServer.addServlet( ctx,  CXFServlet.class.getSimpleName(), CXFServlet.class.getName() );
tServer.getHost().setAutoDeploy(true);
tServer.getHost().setDeployOnStartup(true);
ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/test/*", CXFServlet.class.getSimpleName());
ctx.addApplicationListener(ContextLoaderListener.class.getName());
ctx.addParameter("contextClass",AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName());
ctx.addParameter("contextConfigLocation", RestConfig.class.getName());
    
Class filterClass = DelegatingFilterProxy.class;
FilterDef myFilterDef = new FilterDef();
myFilterDef.setFilterClass(filterClass.getName());
myFilterDef.setFilterName("springSecurityFilterChain");
ctx.addFilterDef(myFilterDef);

FilterMap myFilterMap = new FilterMap();
myFilterMap.setFilterName("springSecurityFilterChain");
myFilterMap.addURLPattern("/*");
ctx.addFilterMap(myFilterMap);

tServer.start();
tServer.getServer().await();
```

**In build.gradle I have added below dependancy,**

`// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core implementation group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.60'`
using above dependacy not able to connect **http://127.0.0.1:4434/test**

If I move to version 8.5.82 its working fine.
I have requirement to use tomcat 9 compatibility, So anyone help me on this.
Didn't found any error log in app.

Comment: I would suggest to move to Spring Boot and use that capability to run the embedded server instead of inventing your own.

Comment: I concur with @M.Deinum that using the standards and not trying to invent your own solutions is generally a good idea. If that is for some reason not an option for you, then adding the logs error messages you get from building/runnning/etc. will be a huge help for us to help you :)

Comment: Actually we are using Spring Boot app,But we have some specific requirement on that to give suchway,    @RohdeFischer Actully I am not getting any log for that, and I didnt get idea to enable its Log. When running it didn't get std log anywhere and trying to see port by netstat but port is not UP

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 9 is not adding a Connector automatically to your server , so you'll have to trigger it yourself using :

```
tServer.getConnector();
```

This will add the default connector to server and server start responding
So code should be like

```
Tomcat tServer = new Tomcat();
tServer.setHostname('127.0.0.1');
tServer.setPort(4434);
tServer.getConnector();
```